# Python 3 counter that is ignoring strings with less than x characters

Tags: python, string, counter, analysis, cpu-word

i have a programm that counts words of a text file. Now i want to restrict the counter to strings with more than x characters

```
from collections import Counter
input = 'C:/Users/micha/Dropbox/IPCC_Boox/FOD_v1_ch15.txt'

Counter = {}
words = {}
with open(input,'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    word_list = line.replace(',','').replace('\'','').replace('.','').lower().split()
    for word in word_list:
      if word not in Counter:
        Counter[word] = 1
      else:
        Counter[word] = Counter[word] + 1
N = 20
top_words = Counter(Counter).most_common(N)
for word, frequency in top_words:
    print("%s %d" % (word, frequency))
```

I tried the `re` code, but it did not work.

```
    re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b')
```

I dont know how to implement it...

At the end I would like to have an output that ignores all the short words like and, you, be etc.

Comment: why constructing manual Counter?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this more simply with:

```
  for word in word_list:
      if len(word) < 5:   # check the length of each word is less than 5 for example
          continue        # this skips the counter portion and jumps to next word in word_list
      elif word not in Counter:
          Counter[word] = 1
      else:
          Counter[word] = Counter[word] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Few notes.

1) You import a `Counter` but don't use it properly (you do a `Counter = {}` thus overwriting the import).

```
from collections import Counter
```

2) Instead of doing several `replace`s use list comprehension with a `set`, its faster and only does one (two with the join) iterations instead of several:

```
sentence = ''.join([char for char in line if char not in {'.', ',', "'"}])
word_list = sentence.split()
```

3) Use the counter and list comp for length:

```
c = Counter(word for word in word_list if len(word) > 3)
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Counter already does what you want. You can "feed" it wiht an iterable and this will work.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects
You can use the filter function too https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter
The could look alike:

`counted = Counter(filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5, words))`